# electron-react-boilerplate calling electron api

Tags: reactjs, electron

I was trying to open up a dialog which is provides by `Electron` API by clicking a button from UI (using `react`)

here is my code

```
// @flow
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { ipcRenderer, ipcMain, dialog } from 'electron'

ipcMain.on('open-information-dialog', function (event) {
  const options = {
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Information',
    message: "This is an information dialog. Isn't it nice?",
    buttons: ['Yes', 'No']
  }
  dialog.showMessageBox(options, function (index) {
    event.sender.send('information-dialog-selection', index)
  })
})

export default class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
  };

  handleClick() {
    console.log("test");
    ipc.send('open-information-dialog');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>test</button>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @MikePerrenoud yeah, ipcMain is undefined when assign `on` event